# Get textual representation of LLVM IR from module obejct

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I'm currently working on a compiler for a C/C++ like language. I have reached the compiling phase of code generation. I'm using the LLVM C++ api to create an LLVM IR from the input file.

As far as I understood it my module object (I'm working with just one module) should contain all information I need for getting the textual representation of the LLVM IR as a string.

But I really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get the LLVM IR of your `llvm::Module` you can use the `llvm::Module::print` function. Use this in combination with the LLVM standard streams like this:

```cpp
llvm::Module module = ...
module.print(llvm::errs()); // for stderr, llvm::outs() for stdout
```

Answer (score 2):

See also [dump()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Module.html#acf2ab2f5fc12e938c8397375d29a580f):

```cpp
module.dump();  // print to stderr
```

Or use [raw_ostream](https://llvm.org/doxygen/raw__ostream_8h.html)

```cpp
llvm::outs() << module;
// or
llvm::errs() << module;
// or
llvm::dbgs() << module;
```